# SQL Query count issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've two tables `artist` and `members`. artist has zero to many relation with members. (one artist may have 0 or many members)

So, I want to get all the fields of artist with the total number of members, that he has.

I write a query, but, it returns `0` count if there is no artist in the table (artist table is empty). I am using this query

```
SELECT a.artistname, count(m.id) as total 
    FROM artist a, members m 
    WHERE m.artist_id = a.id
```

It should simply not return anything if there is no artist.

Thank you!

[image: Please check the result in image]

Comment: This is correct SQL result for your query. There is nothing wrong with it, because you are using `COUNT()` function.

Comment: I want to get the artistname with the number of members.
so, if there is no artist, it means, there should not be any member associated with that artist and number of records should be 0.
but, here it is showing 1 record. there is no artist. so, artistname is NULL and count is also showing that's not suppose to be there.

Comment: That is what it will show, why dont you use php to change what you want to display i.e if 0 echo'Null';

Comment: Its not a best practice to handle queries using script. I believe that there should be a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: If you want `artist name` and `member count` you should be using a `group by`. I dont see any `group by` clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your field name is `artistname` in the `artist` table,

The query should go like this:

```
SELECT artist.artistname, COUNT(members.id) AS total_members
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN members ON members.artis_id = artist.id
GROUP BY artist.artistname
```

Use join, and to use sql `count` you need to use `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   SELECT a.artistname, 
          count(m.id)
     FROM artist a
LEFT JOIN members m 
       ON m.artist_id = a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the artistname is empty. Did you check the data? You could try the following modified query:

```
SELECT a.artistname, count(m.id) as total 
FROM artist a, members m 
WHERE m.artist_id = a.id
AND   a.artistname is NOT NULL
AND   a.artistname <> '';
```